# Method not found error in referenced dll

Tags: c#

In my web application I am referencing 3 DLLs from a project. The project was built a while ago and I have the DLLs in a folder.

The problem is when I change something in to the reference DLLs source project and try to deploy the latest DLLs my web application fails saying `Method not found`.

I have checked GAC and elsewhere but could not find a fix to this particular issue.

Comment: Are these dlls signed with strong names or no?

Comment: Yes the dlls are signed with strong name

Comment: Try to set `Specific Version` property of dlls references to 'True'